# Is there a way I can call a function for each html element when iterated using javascript loops

Tags: javascript, html, loops, ecmascript-6, getelementbyid

I have HTML elements iterated using a javascript loop

The html looks like this

```
<div class="description">Item 1</div>
<div class="description">Item 2</div>
<div class="description">Item 2</div>
```

The Javascript

```
let allItems =  document.querySelectorAll(".description")
  for (let i = 0; i <= allItems.length; i++) {
      allItems[i].addEventListener("click", toggleSpinner.bind(this));
     }
```

```
toggleSpinner = () => {
        alert("I clicked") // here should be, for example, "I clicked Item 1,
                           // Or Item 2 or Item 3 depending on which was clicked
      },
```

How do I call the function independently when each of the element is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this maybe?

```js
toggleSpinner = (data) => {
  console.log(`You clicked item ${data}`) // here should be, for example, "I clicked Item 1,
  // Or Item 2 or Item 3 depending on which was clicked
}


let allItems =  document.querySelectorAll(".description")
for (let i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
 allItems[i].addEventListener("click", toggleSpinner.bind(this, allItems[i].dataset.item));
}
```

```html
<div class="description" data-item="1">Item 1</div>
<div class="description" data-item="2">Item 2</div>
<div class="description" data-item="3">Item 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

let allItems =  document.querySelectorAll(".description")
  for (let i = 0; i <= allItems.length; i++) {
      allItems[i].addEventListener("click", () => {toggleSpinner(allItems[i].innerHTML)});
     }

toggleSpinner = content => {
        alert(`I clicked ${content}`)
      },

Something like that. Add a parameter to the function and define what you want to add as this content in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div > *').click(function(){
    alert('hi');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p> This is a paragraph </p>
  <section> This is a section </section>
  <span> This is a span </span>
  <article> This is an article </article>

</div>
```

Comment: Not really. Each of the elements should have the event listener attached and when a element is clicked, It calls a function independently. Like in its own instance. Also I would prefer it not to be dependent on jquery

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("getClickedElement").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("Clicked element is:- ", event.target.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="getClickedElement">
  <div class="description">Item 1</div>
  <div class="description">Item 2</div>
  <div class="description">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Note:- Simply You have to wrap all the elements inside the parent div & bind [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with that element. you will get targeted element data.